# How can I get keyboard inputs when not focused to the JavaFX stage?

Tags: java, javafx

I'm trying to understand how can I get the keyboard inputs without being focused to my JavaFX stage .
Usually when I want to get a key input I'm doing this:

```
    public class Controller implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    Button btn ;

    @FXML
    VBox vBox ;

    @Override
    public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
        vBox.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent>() {
            @Override
            public void handle(javafx.scene.input.KeyEvent event) {
                System.out.print(event.getCode());
            }
        });
    }

}
```

But how can I get the input when I'm not focused to my Program ?

Answer (score 3):

This isn't possible using pure Java, since Java is running in the JVM you are not able to listen to global keystrokes.

You could use a JNI library like [jnativehook](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook) to perform your desired task. I once used it myself in a project and it's quite simple. Here a code snippet how it is done:

```
import org.jnativehook.GlobalScreen;
import org.jnativehook.NativeHookException;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyEvent;
import org.jnativehook.keyboard.NativeKeyListener;

class Example implements NativeKeyListener {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Example();
    }

    public Example() {
        try {
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
        } catch (NativeHookException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent ev) {
        // check your specific key press here
        // example:
        if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_H) {
            // the key "h" is pressed
            System.out.println("Hello!");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {}

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {}
}
```

You just have to add the *jnativehook-2.0.3.jar* to your build path and you are good to go.

**edit:** A short and clumsy example regarding the comments.

```
class Example implements NativeKeyListener {

        private Robot bot;
        private boolean ctrlPressed = false;
        private TextArea textArea1;
        private TextArea textArea2;
        // more TextAreas ...

        public Example(TextArea textArea1, TextArea textArea2) throws Exception {
            this.textArea1 = textArea1;
            this.textArea2 = textArea2;
            // ...
            bot = new Robot();

            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
            logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);

            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(this);
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent ev) {
            if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_L) {
                ctrlPressed = true; // ctrl key is pressed
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent ev) {
            if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_CONTROL_L) {
                ctrlPressed = false; // ctrl key is released
            }
            if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_1 && ctrlPressed) { // check if ctrl + 1 is used
                Clipboard clipboard = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
                StringSelection stringSelection = new StringSelection(textArea1.getText()); // adding content of textArea1
                clipboard.setContents(stringSelection, stringSelection); // copy content to the system clipboard
                bot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V); // use (ctrl+)v to paste current clipboard content
                bot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
            }
            if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_2 && ctrlPressed) {
                // same as for ctrl+1 with the content of textArea2
            }
            // further if statements for the different key combinations and text areas
            // ....
        }

        @Override
        public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent arg0) {} // irrelevant
    }
```

Comment: Thank you ! can i stop the non-stop console printing ?!?

Comment: @user2697241 Yes. Just add `Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
  logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);` before you register the hook using `GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();`

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know how can I do a paste command ? that will do a paste of text to the screen. I'm trying to do a  multiple copy and paste app ..

Comment: @user2697241 What exactly do you want to do? Print the text you copied in the console if pressing a specific key or the standard ctrl+v? You could just access the clipboard and fetch the current content for example.

Comment: I'm trying to build a Copy Paste program .. if the user will pres CTRL+1 he will get some text that he have put , if he will press CTRL+2 he will get other text that he put . what I need to know is how can I do a paste command for every time that he press . I will take the text from text area and paste the text in the window that the user want to like a simple paste command .

Comment: If I understand you correctly you have multiple text areas containing the different texts you want to paste? So one text area for ctrl+1, one for ctrl+2, ..... and if you are going to press the specific combination you would like the text to be pasted? You could just work with the two methods `public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent ev)` and `public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent ev)` and set a flag if CTRL is pressed and print one specific text if 1, 2, 3 or whatever is released.

Comment: Exactly ! But I dont know how to paste the text to any window... do you know how ?

Comment: @user2697241 You could use the [Clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) in combination with [Robot](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) to write the content of your specific textarea into the clipboard and paste it executing ctrl+v with robot. And stop writing "Any suggestions ?" all the time please...

Comment: The clipboard will let me paste data to any window ? Even I'm not focused to my program? Like the JNI ?

Comment: @user2697241 Exactly. You are using the normal system clipboard, so it's globally present.

Comment: Ok ! So you are saying that I can perform a ctrl+c and ctrl+ with the Clipboard and the Robot ? Do you have any example ??

Comment: @user2697241 That's what I am saying. Since you want to implement a copy paste application and not me, I am going to provide you one last example how it could be done.... Look at my answer above.