# Check a checkbox with JavaFX using a keyboard key

Tags: javascript, java

Hey so I am working on an autoclicker with random delays etc for a friend but he has asked for me to make a UI with javafx. I said ok but now I need to toggle the autoclicker by pressing the key "r". My code is as follows, I decided on checkbox so I can know whether it is toggled or not but I want to make it so that I can press r to check the checkbox and press again to uncheck therefore stopping the autoclicker. Thanks in advance.

```js
public class MainFrame extends Application {

 CheckBox toggleclick;

  @Override
     public void start(Stage primaryStage) {

    GridPane grid = new GridPane();
         grid.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
         grid.setHgap(10);
         grid.setVgap(10);
         grid.setPadding(new Insets(25, 25, 25, 25));

    Text scenetitle = new Text("11.1 CPS Clicker");
         scenetitle.setFont(Font.font("Tahoma", FontWeight.NORMAL, 30));
         grid.add(scenetitle, 0, 0, 2, 1);

         CheckBox cb = new CheckBox();
         cb.setText("Begin Clicking");


         HBox hbBtn = new HBox(10);
         hbBtn.setAlignment(Pos.BOTTOM_RIGHT);
         hbBtn.getChildren().add(cb);
         grid.add(hbBtn, 1, 4);

         final Text actiontarget = new Text();
         grid.add(actiontarget, 1, 6);

         cb.setOnAction(new EventHandler<ActionEvent>() {

             @Override
             public void handle(ActionEvent e) {
                 
              while (true) {
            try {
             Mouse.sendLeftClick();
            } catch (AWTException e1) {
             e1.printStackTrace();
            }
                  double deviation = 22;
                  double mean = 90;
                  int min = 43;
                  int max = 198;
                  Random r = new Random();
                  double randGauss = (r.nextGaussian() * deviation);
                  long delayPreClamp = Math.round(randGauss + mean);
                  long delay = (long) MathUtil.clamp(delayPreClamp, min, max);
                  try {
                      Thread.sleep(delay);
                  } catch (InterruptedException e2) {
                      e2.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
             }
         });

         Scene scene = new Scene(grid, 325, 250);
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();

         primaryStage.setTitle("AutoClicker");
         primaryStage.setScene(scene);
         primaryStage.show();
     }
  public static void main(String[] args) {
         launch(args);
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to create an new EventHandler to define an event when a key is pushed, like this :

```
cb.setOnKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>() {
                @Override
                public void handle(KeyEvent event) {
                   if("R".equals(ke.getText().toUpperCase() )) {
                       if(cb.isSelected()) {
                          cb.setSelected(false);
                        } else {
                          cb.setSelected(true);
                        }
                   }
                });
```

ke.getText() returns the value of the pressed key, and if it's R, you check or uncheck the checkBox.

Comment: thanks very much for the reply, this could be solution but when I press again does it toggle off? I can't test atm.

Comment: Hey thanks for the quick reply, does this go above or under the setOnAction?

Comment: I'm not sure (because I use the software Scene Builder to create my JavaFX UIs) but I think you can put it above or under, as you want. Because it's 2 independant eventHandler

Comment: Alright just tried it, got the error on "onKeyPressed"

`The method onKeyPressed(new EventHandler<KeyEvent>(){}) is undefined for the type CheckBox`

P.S with setOnKeyPressed it works but doesn't toggle anything, it checks the box but doesn't cause it to do the event pasted above... However when I tick it myself it does it.

Comment: You're right, the EventHandler<KeyEvent> doesn't trigger the EventHandler<ActionEvent>. I will search how to do that.

Comment: Don't worry, it's rewarding for me too ! I'm a French developer, and try to find solutions for this kind of issues allows me to improve my skills ! For the moment, I don't know how trigger an the EventHandler<ActionEvent> with an EventHandler<KeyEvent>. But maybe for your problem, can you just deplace the code from the ActionEvent to the KeyEvent ?

Comment: I put

`if(cb.isSelected() == true) {`
and then I put my my autoclicking code (the one under cb.setOnAction) seen in my first post. It didn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: I think the problem is the loop in the autoclicking code. The program is blocked in the loop and it can't receive the second keyevent. I think the solution is to use a second thread for the autoclicking code

Comment: Sorry i don't quite understand...  what are you suggesting I do?

Comment: Do you know what is a Thread ? It's a small process, and a program can have several Threads. Currently, you have only one Thread (the main Thread) in your code. So, you can't do several things in the same time. I'm suggesting to create a second thread which will execute your autoclicking code. So, the main Thread could receive the keyevents and simply start and stop the second thread. I'm sorry, I don't know if it's clear for you...

Comment: So a completely separate class?

Comment: Yes ! And you put your autoclicking code in the run() method of this Class.

Comment: alright awesome I got it working thanks so much! I only have one issue now and that is that I want to be able to toggle the code even if my program isn't the one in focus! Do you have an idea on how to do that? Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: I think it's not possible with JavaFX, but I found this for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33503293/how-can-i-get-keyboard-inputs-when-not-focused-to-the-javafx-stage It could be useful

Comment: Ah ok, do you have any idea how I can make it work with mine x.x

Comment: If you absolutely want to be able toggle the code even if your program isn't the one in focus, I think you had to use the Snu's Solution. This solution is to create a new class which will replace the basic key listener of JavaFX. So, the best solution is to remove all your key listeners of JavaFX and replace them by your own listener.

Comment: O my goodness, I made it work, though it doesn't stop for some reason? any solutions?

Comment: I don't know, what did you do ?

Comment: I put the main clicker code inside of the part that says
`if(ev.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_R) {`

Although it does say while(true){ for the start of the code but without that it only runs once...

Comment: Have you read the comments ? Seems user2697241 had the same issue (with a non-stop printing) and Snu found the solution (with a logger)

Comment: I tried that but:

logger.setLevel(Level.OFF);

gives me errors.

Multiple markers at this line
 - Syntax error, insert ")" to complete MethodDeclaration
 - Syntax error on token ".", @ expected after this token
 - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
  MethodHeaderName
 - Syntax error, insert "SimpleName" to complete 
  QualifiedName